# Clean up scraped tweets with note++ and regular expression

Tags: twitter, tweets

I would like to know please how to remove all @mentions, #hashtags, and URLs http.... from a list of scraped tweets from twitter.

I've tried (and failed) using:

```
find all [@].* and replace with blank
find all [#].* and replace with blank
find all [http].* and replace with blank
```

etc etc...this just complete removes almost everything from my scraped results.

I'm new to notepad and trying to sort through all the information.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm assuming you mean Notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is too broad.  Try this:

```
(@|#|http)\S+
```

Or, depending on your regex flavor, you may need to write out `\S` (non-whitespace) as

```
(@|#|http)[^ ]+
```

Of course, with regex, it's all about knowing exactly what you want, which you usually figure out along the way.

Comment: Very close, yet still way too destructive to the tweets...I tried exactly the code you gave and they didn't do anything so I replaced the ( with [ and ) with ]. both examples did remove everything I wanted to remove but the also removed a lot of the letters from the words in the tweets. for example the word 'alcohol' turned to 'alco'   yes notepad++